# making calculations with data that is registered to the database

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, typescript

I am developing an angularly connected program to mongodb.
but I encountered a problem.
My problem:
I entered Mongodb database on the keyboard.
But I want to do mathematical calculations with the data entered from the keyboard and I want to save the calculated data to the database.
how can I do it ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide the code that you have so far? Much easier to help you that way

Answer (score 0):

You need to make all calculations with code and the just save it to db, that is the first steps in development. Read some guides, docs, etc. For example [here](https://ramlez.com/blog/node-js-typescript-2-x-mongodb-quick-start-2/) or [here](https://brianflove.com/2016/10/04/typescript-declaring-mongoose-schema-model/). Alse there is good [guide](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-6-mean-stack-crash-course-part-1-front-end-project-setup-and-routing-89bec8332cea) for MEAN stack

P. S.: Welcome to Stack :)